# Connecting to ssh server that only accepts local connections

Tags: ssh, vpn

This is the situation right now if I want to connect to my university server for using some statistical software made available.

1. I connect my laptop to the university VPN
2. I use putty to establish an ssh connection with the server
3. If I try to establish an ssh connection with the server without connecting to the VPN first, the connection times out every time, nothing happens

I was wondering if there was a way where I could connect to the ssh server without having to connect to the VPN first. Maybe just build in the VPN credentials in the putty authentication session somehow?

I want to be able to do this on both a windows and Ubuntu box.

Comment: Is there any way that I can move it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only a moderator has the capability to do this, though you may have the option yourself somewhere; I've flagged it anyway, so a mod will see the flag...

Comment: I think the best you could do is script it out somehow. SSH and VPN are two completely different technologies. SSH can run as an unprivileged user but VPN assigns an additional IP to your computer and changes how traffic is routed through the OS which is much more involved.

Comment: I see. Well this helps because I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this, or some tool written by someone. I do not wish to spend a lot of time trying to achieve this.